# Show $a\times (b \times ( c \times a)) = (a\cdot b)(a\times c)$ for vectors $a,b,c$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

> For $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^3$, show that $$a\times (b \times ( c \times a)) = (a\cdot b)(a\times c)$$

I get to $-a\times(b\cdot a)c$ and eliminating the minus sign gives me $c\times a$ instead of $a\times c$. 
Can anybody help me to see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should include your work up to that point, otherwise we cannot help you see where you went wrong.

Comment: I've found my mistake now, I'll do that next time

Answer (score 1):

From [Vector Triple Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html) you have:
$$b \times(c \times a)=c(b \cdot a)-a(b \cdot c)$$
So:
$$a \times (b \times(c \times a)) = a \times (c(b \cdot a)-a(b \cdot c))$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I'd written down the identity the wrong way in my notes

Comment: @srees You're welcome. My teacher told us it a way like this: Always take out the middle vector, multiply it by the other 2's product. Then take the other vector from the brackets and multiply it by the other 2's product and subtract it from the first.